# I want to edit checkout page in shopify, can it will be possible in shopify normal edition

Tags: shopify, checkout

I want to edit discount text to be hide from checkout page, can it will be possible in shopify normal edition, because I cannot find any checkout.liquid file in backend.

Comment: No, checkout.liquid file is only available into Shopify plus plan.

Comment: https://shopify.dev/api/functions

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, Editing checkout to hide elements/hide text is not possible on `Shopify` normal edition/normal plans, it's only available on `Shopify Plus` plan.

however, you can only change the text language/text formatting to be another text, but it can't be left blank,

1. From your Shopify admin, go to Settings > Checkout and accounts.
2. In the Checkout language section, click Manage checkout language.
3. Make your changes to the checkout fields.
4. Click Save.

more info here:
https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/checkout-settings/checkout-language